# React does not recognize the 'activeKey' (and 'activeHref') prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom

I've been continuously having this warning on my React web application and not sure how I can fix this. I'm pretty new to React and have tried googling my way through, but still haven't ended up in a solution.

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `activeKey` prop on a DOM element. If 
         you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom 
         attribute, spell it as lowercase `activekey` instead. If you 
         accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the 
         DOM element.
    in div (created by NavbarForm)
    in NavbarForm (created by Header)
    in ul (created by Nav)
    in Nav (created by Header)
    in div (created by Grid)
    in Grid (created by Navbar)
    in nav (created by Navbar)
    in Navbar (created by Uncontrolled(Navbar))
    in Uncontrolled(Navbar) (created by Header)
    in Header (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App
```

Here is the code for my Header

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, FormControl, FormGroup, Nav, Navbar, NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';

const Header = (props : any) => {
    return (
        <Navbar>
            <Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Brand>
                    <NavItem href="/">
                        RedQuick
                    </NavItem>
                </Navbar.Brand>
            </Navbar.Header>
            <Nav>
                <Navbar.Form>
                    <form onSubmit={ props.getRedditPost }>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <FormControl 
                                type="text" 
                                name="subreddit" 
                                placeholder="Subreddit Name..." 
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                        <Button type="submit">Search</Button>
                    </form>
                </Navbar.Form>                
            </Nav>
        </Navbar>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

[Link to Github repo if its not the header's problem](https://github.com/Hyokune/Sample/tree/master/application_1)

Comment: Having DOM elements as Nav children might be the issue: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2199

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=activeKey+activeHref) found me [this issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap/issues/194), which indicates that putting `<Navbar.Form>` inside `<Nav>` is not valid.  Looking at the example in [the documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#navbars-form), it may work to just remove the `<Nav>`.