# React Warnings - does not recognize activeKey, activeHref prop on DOM element, using React-Bootstrap Navbar Components

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

I notice this is somewhat of a duplicate question, as there is [this post with a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51852390/react-does-not-recognize-the-activekey-and-activehref-prop-on-a-dom-elemen) - however my code does not have a `<Navbar-Form>` inside of a `<Nav>`, and as such, I am not sure what is wrong with my ordering of `Navs`.

The return function of the NavBar component in my React app that is throwing the warmings looks as such:

```
    myItems = someArray.map(function (app, i) {
        return (
            <Col key={'navitem-' + i}>
                <NavItem key={app + '-' + i} componentClass='span'>
                    <Link exact='true' className='nav-link' to={app.route}>
                        {app.name}
                    </Link>
                </NavItem>
            </Col>
        );
    });

    return( 
        <Navbar
            collapseOnSelect
            className={'navbar-orange' + (this.props.visible ? '' : ' hidden') + (this.state.sticky ? ' sticky-nav' : '') }>

            <Navbar.Collapse>
                <Nav activeKey={2}>
                    <NavDropdown id={'needs-an-id'} eventKey={1} title={league} onSelect={this.handleAlert}>
                        <MenuItem eventKey={'NBA'} componentClass='span'>
                          NBA
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey={'NHL'} componentClass='span'>
                          NHL
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey={'MLB'} componentClass='span'>
                          MLB
                        </MenuItem>
                    </NavDropdown>

                    <Grid>
                        <Row>
                            {myItems}
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
```

Is there some component that i am incorrectly nesting inside of some other component? If it helps to give a sense for what the code is doing, this code is for the orange NavBar that can be found on [my website here](https://bigleaguegraphs.com/nba/shot-charts). If there is some documentation that indicates what nesting of react-bootstrap navbar components is and isnt allowed, sharing that would be super helpful as well!

Edit: for some context as to what is going on. I need an array of many `<NavItem>` with links that link from page to page on my website. However, the array of `<NavItems>` that should show **depends on which of the 3 menu items is selected** in the `<NavDropdown>` (one of NBA, MLB, or NHL). Once again, clicking around on the NavBar on the actual site that I linked to will help with this.

Thanks in advance very much!